# Navigate problems with Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i'm working with **Ionic Framework** and i've the next problem.

I have 3 views templates: **one.html**, **two.html**, **three.html**, and **one.html** is the home of the application (no back button)

The navigation is correct between the views but i have problems if navigate from **three.html** to **one.html** because when navigate to **one.html** in navbar appears the back button and i need **one.html** identical as app start state

I navigate with `$state.go('tab.one.html');`

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code. At least from your stateProvider and the link.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the nav-clear directive to do this [(source)](http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/navClear/)

or implement the code directly in your controller:

```
$ionicViewService.nextViewOptions({
  disableAnimate: true,
  disableBack: true
});
```

Comment: Perfect. $ionicViewService is deprecated. Is better $ionicHistory.nextViewOption

Comment: Great! Thanks for the heads up. Wasn't aware of that change =)